# Plant identification please of tree growing on my verge, and looks like an egg plant

Tags: identification

I think it's a noxious plant but I can't recall the name. Growing Wellington, New Zealand.

[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: It's arising from two sources in the ground and growing alongside the tree.  It's about 5 foot tall.

Comment: I think it might be a woolly nightshade Solanum mauritianum

Comment: Hi Graham! Would you kindly add some detail to the title of your question, including a quick description of the major features of the plant? It's much easier for people when they're looking at titles to get a sense of what to expect in the question. Repeating the major features in the question itself is also appreciated. This [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) teaches the best way to write a great identification question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am so excited!  I think I found it!  The Wild Tobacco Tree; Solanum mauntianum

I would think it was poisonous just by the Genus.  Had to get my answer in...a weed of course.

[Wild Tobacco Tree](https://weeds.brisbane.qld.gov.au/weeds/wild-tobacco-tree)

Comment: Well, that was quick!  I'm going to cut it down now :)

Comment: It was!  New Zealand has a very concise repertoire of a list of plants...that guy just popped right up first thing.

Comment: I cut it right back and it's right up there again but bigger than before. Needs a weed killer :(